# PHP не видит в массиве значение, хотя оно там есть

Tags: массивы, php

Я ничего не понимаю, у меня вот такая вот проблемка. PHP отказывается видеть в массиве значение, но оно там есть, вот скриншот дампов:

[image]

Код:

```
var_dump($tm[0]);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($tm[1]);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($teams[$tm[0]]);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($teams[$tm[1]]);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($teams);
```

И я не понимаю, почему `$teams[$tm[0]]` ищется нормально, а `$teams[$tm[1]]` нет. Хотя все идентично, названия совпадают, проблема лишь с `$teams[$tm[1]]`.

Помогите, кто может, пожалуйста :)
Заранее огромное спасибо)

Комментарии:

[image]

Comment: Предоставьте вывод вот таких данных:

    print_r(array($tm, $teams));
    var_dump($tm, $teams);

А там дальше посмотрим. 

И да, какие ошибки то пишет?

Comment: Я забыл добавить, что $tm[0] и $tm[1] вычисляются в массиве и изменяются постоянно, а $teams собирается до этого массива, кусок вставил в вопрос скриншотом.

Comment: А ошибку выдает такую: Notice: Undefined index: VFL LONDON in *адрес_файла* on line 51 NULL 
Строка 51: var_dump($teams[$tm[1]]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было нормально, моя проблема была в том, что был незакрытый элемент </b>, отображался только в исходном коде страницы, убрал его и все нормально.